# Align Icon on Center Using Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an icon that I want to align on center. My problem is that, it doesn't align well.
I'm using styled components.

Here's my codesandbox
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-d8xkh?file=/Video.js)

```
const Play = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Play = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
`;
```

removed `top` and `left`, put VideoBanner, Play inside `div`, and added some style.

```
style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
```

Check here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-h746n?file=/Video.js)

Answer (score 0):

The Icon is already at center but from its left edge. For you requirement add `transform: translateX(-50%);` to your Play

```js
const Play = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
`;
```

This will translate to left by 50% of its own width

Comment: the left and right is fixed but the top and bottom isn't. It still a bit too low?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the play button starts its division from top and left at 50%. For example width of your division is 100px, that division will start at at 50% (center of parent div) to 50% + 100px that's why it shows up little bit right aligned.

you have to make your play styled component like:

```
const Play = styled.div`
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
`;
```

Here is the example as you want. Please [CHECK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-okw58?file=/Video.js)